# Why is my Visual Studio highlighting so bad for C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, darkmode

So I just installed One Dark Pro for Visual Studio (IDE) as it is the most used and also my preferred theme for Text Editors. However, it happens that my syntax highlighting for C++ language is absolutely DISASTREOUS!

Just look at it:
[image]

I tried to reset the default color theme but it doesn't work, it appears that they're the default colors of the theme but it surprises me as it's not natural.

Is it normal or is there a way to change these awful colors?

Comment: That's nasty.  My Visual Studio certainly does not look like that.  I'm using the built-in Dark theme.  Tools > Options > Environment > General > Color theme

Comment: So, you use an extension that changes colours and then wonder why the colours are those? You can customize all the colours of different aspects of the language...

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Community, Enterprise or Pro? Or are you using VSCode which is a completely different IDE from Microsoft.

Comment: Is this caused by One Dark Pro because they are not the default colors of dark theme.

Comment: I just switched to Visual Studio 2022 and it is good again lol

Answer (score 0):

This is the option I found in Visual Studio (Tools > Options) to make `cout` bad. Click `Use Default` to reset it.

[image]

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately